# Sorting Spring table by clicking on column header

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple HTML table, which gets data from Repository (extends JpaRepository). At the moment I have simple pagination and sorting via lastName. I would like to sort table by clicking on column headers so for example I could sort data by price or address.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String userList(
    Model model,
    @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 50, sort = "lastName", direction = Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable)
{
    model.addAttribute("page", userService.findAll(pageable));
    return "user/list";
}
```

Comment: I tweaked the title, removed some unneeded fluff ("thanks" and "help" are implied), and made the code and body a bit more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Call the `list` url with following parameters.

```
list?sort=price,ASC
list?sort=price,DESC
list?sort=address,ASC
list?sort=address,DESC
```

`price` and `address` must be Entity bean variable name. ASC, DESC can be used based on the order you want.

Comment: via controller or view? do you have some example?
i have to handle my pagination aswell

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I tried a ton of different urls like `sort.dir=ASC` and `price.dir=ASC` before I stumbled upon this and it worked.

Comment: @Danny It is coming from PageRequest which will be processed by the PageableArgumentResolver http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableArgumentResolver.html